# Refreshing Spring Bean during runtime

Tags: java, spring

I have an XML file where the value of XML is taken in spring bean object. I'm using a file watcher to check if the XML is being modified. IF its been modified, i have to refresh the spring bean object during runtime.

```
    import java.nio.file.Path;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKind;
    import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
    import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
    import java.nio.file.WatchService;
    import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //define a folder root
        Path myDir = Paths.get("D:/data");       

        try {
           WatchService watcher = myDir.getFileSystem().newWatchService();
           myDir.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKind.ENTRY_CREATE, 
           StandardWatchEventKind.ENTRY_DELETE, StandardWatchEventKind.ENTRY_MODIFY);

           WatchKey watckKey = watcher.take();

           List<WatchEvent<?>> events = watckKey.pollEvents();
           for (WatchEvent event : events) {
                if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKind.ENTRY_MODIFY) {
                   //CODE FOR REFRESHING BEAN
                }
             }  
         }
     }
```

Comment: SHow the bean related part and spring init as well. Actually you can access the bean from spring context and change the XML.

Comment: Refactor the watcher into a bean, inject the main bean into the watcher as a member. When the watcher has parsed new and validated data then call methods on the main bean to have it refresh itself from the parsed XML. Watch out for synchronization issues.